# Systemd, Assignment outside of section. Ignoring

Tags: systemd, activemq-artemis

I'm seeing many of the following errors from `systemd` for Apache ActiveMQ Artemis.

```
Sep 25 04:41:17 server systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/artemis.service:1: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
Sep 25 04:41:17 server systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/artemis.service:2: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
```

I took some helpful advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286099/systemd-script-assignment-outside-of-section-missing), but as far as I can tell the file is OK.

```
> file artemis.service
artemis.service: ASCII text
```

So I think the file format is correct, and I don't see any extra characters:

```
> cat -A artemis.service
Description=Apache ActiveMQ Artemis$
After=network.target$
[Service]$
Type=simple$
User=activemq$
Group=activemq$
ExecStart=/var/lib/broker-HA/bin/artemis run$
#ExecStop=/var/lib/broker-HA/bin/artemis stop$
UMask=0007$
RestartSec=10$
Restart=always$
[Install]$
WantedBy=multi-user.target$
```

What might be causing this?

Comment: If you read the error message, lines 1 and 2 have an assignment but are not in a section. So maybe there should be something in square brackets before those? Looking into another unit file, my guess would be `[Unit]`. Not putting as answer, this seems a tad off-topic for SO.

Comment: This is odd. I checked all of my Artemis installations. Different versions, the latest being 2.17. They all have those first two lines before a section.

Comment: did you solve it ?

Answer (score 11):

I got this issue too and solved by adding [Unit] in the .service file.

These 2 lines mean your .service file, 1 and 2 line have errors:

```
/etc/systemd/system/artemis.service:1
/etc/systemd/system/artemis.service:2
```

Solution:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache ActiveMQ Artemis$ 
After=network.target$ 
[Service]$ 
Type=simple$ 
User=activemq$ 
Group=activemq$ 
ExecStart=/var/lib/broker-HA/bin/artemis run$ 
#ExecStop=/var/lib/broker-HA/bin/artemis stop$ 
UMask=0007$ RestartSec=10$ Restart=always$ 
[Install]$ 
WantedBy=multi-user.target$
```

You may have a try :)

Comment: Solved a problem I was having with plexmediaserver on ubuntu 22.04.  Thanks!